# How to deploy python flask application in conda base environment on IIS server?

Tags: python, iis, flask, anaconda, conda

I want to deploy a flask REST API application on IIS server to publish some ML APIs. I have installed Anaconda to run the app on its base environment as I have some data science libraries to import. I followed this link for deployment and it is working fine for the example given in the tutorial https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8. but in my app imports to pandas is not working. It seems my app is not running on conda base environment. Can anybody help me what configuration I need to add so that my app runs on conda base environment.

Comment: you also need to set another environment variable which is WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER and WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_ACTIVATE_THIS , WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER, which is actually your app

Comment: your web.config file: <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.handler"/>
    <!-- Make sure HOSTNAME\IIS_IUSRS can write to this -->
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="c:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc1\wsgi.txt"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="c:\inetpub\pyroot\default" />
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER" value="myapp.app" />
    <add key="WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_ACTIVATE_THIS" value="c:\inetpub\pyroot\default\env\Scripts\activate_this.py" />
  </appSettings>

Comment: <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI"
           path="handler.fcgi"
           verb="*"
           modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="c:\Anaconda\python.exe|c:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.pyc"
           resourceType="Unspecified"
           requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>

Comment: Thanks for you inputs @JalpaPanchal. I think the configuration you specified works for deploying flask on azure using virtualenv as runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with Anaconda Python 3.7.4, When I downgraded it to 3.6.5 it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by giving the IIS site permission to access the dlls on which pandas is dependant. See my solution in this answer

[Deploying Python Flask Application on IIS with wfastcgi in Python 3.7+ with Numpy, Pandas, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682029/deploying-python-flask-application-on-iis-with-wfastcgi-in-python-3-7-with-nump/66682030#66682030)